# TinyMCE does not output font size and font family in the editor after saving

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, tinymce

I have a backend in Codeigniter.
I am using TinyMCE.

I wrote a demo text and made it bold and added more text in the next line with different font family and font size.

The values getting saved in the database is as follows :

```
<code>
<p><strong>HELLO !!!</strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><span  36pt; font-family: terminal, monaco;"><strong>Hello</strong></span></p>
```

So, When i echo this on the editor in the backend after saving , it does not reflect the font family and font size.

I tried using [htmlentities()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) and [html_entity_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) but no use.

I need to `echo` it in the backend editor and the front end page as well.

I am using the Codeigniter framework.

My controller function is something like this :

```
<code>
if($this->form_validation->run())
        {
            $page_data = array(
                'content' => $this->input->post('description') ,
                'page_id' => 2
             );

            $data['page_content'] = $this->Admin_model->get_jingles_about();
            if(!empty($data['page_content']))
            {
                $edit = $this->Admin_model->jingles_about_edit($page_data);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Saved successfully');
            }
            else
            {
                $insert = $this->Admin_model->jingles_about_add($page_data);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Saved successfully');
            }
                redirect('admin/jingles_about');
        }
```

Comment: This is malformed HTML, problem is more likely with storing this content into database.

Comment: `font-size: 36pt;` _not_ `36pt;`

Comment: <span style="css properties in here"></span>

Comment: @tommy That is my doubt. I dont know how the data gets stored in tinymce. I referred the docs. It should store the proper html in the database. But it doesn't. Any help on that ?

Comment: You could post _how you store it_ and see why that happens. I always use TinyMCE, even with Codeigniter, and never encountered a problem

Comment: @DamienPirsy I edited the question . Please check

Comment: I found the answer. It was the xss_filtering that needed to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can save to database as bbcode instead of html. Later convert back to html after loading it into editor. TinyMCE have tools for that. Refer the documentation.

Comment: That's not a real solution, just a workaround, and adds an unnecessary processing.

Comment: It is a possible solution; and personally I don't think that it is a good idea to insert html directly to database. Why was bbcodes designed in the first place?

Comment: Why isn't it a good idea to insert html in a database? What harm does it do? Anyway, BBCode was designed (15 years ago) to prevent vulnerabilites by not allowing html (only a whitelist of it)

Answer (score 0):

I am using TinyMCE 4.2.7
This is what I did to save font family, size, bold, underline, italics to save it to database.

Focus on plugins and **toolbar1** --> **fontselect fontsizeselect**

```
tinyMCE.init({
            selector: "#about",
            theme: "modern",
            plugins: [
                "autolink lists link hr ",
                " wordcount ",
                " paste "
            ],
            toolbar1: "undo redo | fontselect fontsizeselect styleselect | bullist numlist | link",
            extended_valid_elements: 'a[href|target=_blank]',
            menubar:false,
            remove_trailing_brs: false,
            force_br_newlines : true,
            force_p_newlines : false,
            forced_root_block : ''
        });
```